# $h_n:=\lvert f-f_n\rvert\to 0\implies\int h_n\, d\mu\to 0$?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> > Let $f,f_n\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ with $f_n\to f\text{ a.s.}$. Define $h_n:=\lvert f-f_n\rvert$. Then $h_n\to 0\text{ a.s.}$. How can I prove that $\int h_n\, d\mu\to 0$?

My idea ia to use the following proposition:

> > $f_n\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ with $f_n\nearrow f$ a.s. and $\sup\int f_n\, d\mu<\infty$, so it is $f\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ and $\int f_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int f\, d\mu$

Here $-h_n\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$, $-h_n\nearrow 0$ a.s. and $\sup\int -h_n\, d\mu<\infty$, so $-\int h_n\, d\mu\nearrow\int 0\, d\mu =0\Leftrightarrow \int h_n\nearrow 0$.

---

Is there another way?

Comment: It doesn't. Let $f = 0$ and $f_n = n \chi_{[0,n]}$, with Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Then $h_n = f_n \to 0$ a.s., while $\int_0^1 h_n dm = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: And if $f:=1_{M^C} f_n$ where $M$ is the nullset where $f_n$ does not converge?

Comment: Changing the value of $f$ on a set of zero measure doesn't change anything about the convergence.

Comment: Another more common question: So from $h_n\to 0$ it does not follow in general that $\lim h_n\, d\mu\to 0$? And one does sentences about convergence if one wants to make such statements?

Comment: Pointwise convergence does not imply $L^1$ convergence without much stronger assumptions (e.g. uniform integrable bound, or monotone convergence).

Answer (score 3):

From Folland's Real Analysis Sec. 2.4, there are 4 examples you should keep in mind with the Lebesgue Measure on modes of convergence:

1. $f_n = \frac{1}{n} \chi_{(0,n)}$
2. $f_n = \chi_{(n,n+1)}$
3. $f_n = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$
4. $f_n = \chi_{[j/2^k,(j+1)/2^k]}$ where $n=2^k+j$ and $0\leq j < 2^k$. So the intervals are $[0,1],[0,1/2],[1/2,1],[0,1/4]...$.

In the first 3 cases, you have uniform, pointwise, a.e. convergence to 0 but not in $L^1$. The fourth converges in $L^1$ to 0 but converges nowhere. Cases 1,2,4 converge in measure, but case 2 is not Cauchy in measure.